# Selecting blank values within a table

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, null

I am selecting the following to remove NULL values from a selection, but unable to remove BLANK values from the selection. Would selecting BLANK values only be done by using a string length of 0?  I do not want any field that is BLANK, NULL, or a email in my selection, because I am trying to move all fields with comments or websites into another field named comments.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", "Contact_Email IS NOT NULL" )
```

Comment: What happens when you run your selection?  Are you saying that nothing is selected, or not everything is selected?

Comment: When I run my selection, only the NULL values are removed, not the blank rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes blank fields can be made up a number of different ways.

- The field could be `NULL` - it doesn't contain any value at all
- The field could be an empty string, but not `NULL` - `""`
- The field could contain a space but nothing else - `" "`

You may need to allow for all these possibilities:

```
query = "Contact_Email IS NOT NULL and Contact_Email != '' and Contact_Email != ' '"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

That said, sometimes an easier way to find if a field contains an email address is to search for the `@` symbol instead:

```
query = "Contact_Email LIKE '%@%'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

---

If you are trying to select the blanks, you can reverse the query, but will need to include `IS NULL`:

```
query = "Contact_Email NOT LIKE '%@%' OR Contact_Email IS NULL"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

The screenshot below shows this query run in the ArcMap Python window, and the selection it produces

[image]

---

**Update based on new information from comments.**

To select records that don't have an email address and are *not* blank use the following query:

```
query = "Contact_Email NOT LIKE '%@%' and Contact_Email <> ''"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("contacts", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56114/discussion-on-answer-by-midavalo-selecting-blank-values-within-a-table).